# Snowflake SQL UDF - Unsupported Subquery Error

Tags: sql, subquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I am creating a Snowflake SQL UDF. I keep running into ******SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated******. I have tried to do several things to go around the issue, this being my latest try.

How can I make this break out of the subquery'ing error?

The UDF should allow one to input their preferred year. Thinking to create a solution by if a year is not provided, the default would be the present year.

```
create or replace function new_value(PRICE float, TYPE varchar, YR_CREATED int, YEAR int)

returns float

as
$$

 
with AGE_OF_PRODUCT as (
    select any_value((YEAR - YR_CREATED)) as AGE ),



  FORMULA as (
    select any_value(AGE) as AGE,
    any_value(case
        when AGE <= 1 then 1
        else 2
    end) as FUNCTION
    from AGE_OF_PRODUCT

  )
  
  select
     any_value(case
        when F.FUNCTION = 1 then (PRICE - (PRICE * R.R1))
        else (PRICE * (1 - (R.R1))) * pow((1-(R.R2)), ((F.AGE - YR_CREATED)-1))
    end) as VALUE
  from FORMULA as F, RATES as R
  where TYPE = R.TYPE_OF_PRODUCT

  
                                      
$$;
```

Comment: your overuse of ANY_VALUE is rather strange, can you explain why you added those?

Comment: any ways, the primary problem is you will be using this UDF in WHERE or SELECT section, and given it is a sub-select that means the resulting code is a COROLATED SUBQUERY, and those have limited support. So to some degree you need to unfold that and just use the UDF to just do the messy math, with no selections from the RATES table, those should be passed in.

Comment: Thanks @SimeonPilgrim! I realized after iterating on my original problem that adding any_value like that was not necessary. I came to a solution that used 'returns table(VALUE float)' btw. But your solution is more optimal. I signed-on today to check on my question and I'm glad to see the great explanation you've provided on my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the main problem is you are likely using the function like:

```
select v.*,
    new_value(v.price, v.type, v.yr_create, v.year) as awesome
from table_with_values as v
```

also your UDF can be rewritten as it stands as:

```
create or replace function new_value(
    PRICE float, 
    TYPE varchar, 
    YR_CREATED int, 
    YEAR int)
returns float
as
$$

    select
        YEAR - YR_CREATED as age,
        case age <= 1
            when true then (PRICE - (PRICE * r.r1))
            else (PRICE * (1 - (r.r1))) * pow((1-(r.r2)), ((age - YR_CREATED)-1))
        end as value
    from rates as r
    where TYPE = r.type_of_product
                      
$$;
```

but if we move the join to rates outside the UDF

```
create or replace function new_value(
    PRICE float, 
    YR_CREATED int, 
    YEAR int,
    rate1 float,
    rate2 float)
returns float
as
$$
    select
        case (YEAR - YR_CREATED) <= 1
            when true then (PRICE - (PRICE * r.r1))
            else (PRICE * (1 - (rate1))) * pow((1-(rate2)), (((YEAR - YR_CREATED) - YR_CREATED)-1))
        end as value;                     
$$;
```

then we can call it like:

```
select v.*,
    new_value(v.price, v.yr_create, v.year, r.r1, r.r2) as awesome
from table_with_values as v
join rates as r 
    on v.type = r.type_of_product
```